# "big enough to do this"

Tags: phrase-usage

My question is what is the difference among these three sentences.

> 1. He is big enough to do such  heavy works.
> 2. He is not big enough to do such heavy works.
> 3. He is small enough to do such  heavy works.

I am so much confused between 2 and 3.Also, I don't get what the 3rd one means.

Comment: He is small enough to climb up that chimney (it is very narrow).

Comment: But what about 1)he is big enough to earn money
2)he is small enough to earn money??

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to ELL.

1. means 'Because he is sufficiently big he can do this.' (If he was smaller he could not do it.)
2. means 'Because he is not sufficiently big, he cannot do it.' (He is too small to do it.)
3. means 'Because he is small he can do this'. (If he was bigger he could not do it.)

Weather Vane's example of number 3 is good. Chimneys are narrow. Only someone small can climb up them. If he gets bigger he will be too big to do it, but perhaps he is young. He is small enough to do it.

Comment: But what about 1)he is big enough to earn money
2)he is small enough to earn money
Why can't we just only use small in 2.

Comment: I'm confused because in my text book there's a sentence, He is small enough to walk. because baby was so small that he couldn't walk. Why they didn't just use small instead of small enough..thank you sir

Comment: We would usually say, 'He is **old** enough to earn money', not **big** enough. Or we might say 'He is not old enough to earn money' or 'He is too young to earn money. Without knowing the context, 'He is small enough to walk' doesn't make sense. [Please use quotation marks ("....") to show what is from the book.] Do you understand the following sentences? I cannot walk under the table because I am too tall. But my child is small enough to walk under the table. I am tall enough to reach the apples on the tree, but my child is not tall enough."

Comment: Sir I have just edited my question please help, now it's better.

Comment: OK. "*He is small enough to do such heavy works*" is nonsense! Sentences 1 and 2 are fine, though we say *work* in this context, not *works*. The third sentence means "He can do such heavy work because he is small!" How can being small enable you to do heavy work?!

Comment: Sir now this one is our chem book"the
energy gap between the two sets (3d and 4s) of orbitals is small enough
to prevent electron entering the 3d orbitals."but it doesn't prevent so why they didn't just use small,small enough is meaning less here.plase help

Comment: Please tell me when you have understood my previous answers.

Comment: Sir please see this and help really I need this to be solved
https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/144253/about-d-block-elements

Comment: The grammar is correct. There is one typing error. I don't know whether the statement is true or not. It says .....the energy gap prevents electron entering the 3d orbitals. [I guess it means either "the electron" or "electron**s**".] Because the the gap is small, it prevents the electrons entering...

Comment: No sir when gap is small then only electron can pass, more gap means no passing. So could it be a grammatically incorrect or misprint or just idiomatic sentence ? please help

Comment: Read my comment!

Comment: Thanks sir so it's a print mistake, I couldn't understand it.now just to verify it should be small instead of small enough right?

Comment: Yep sir you are right but if so it would mean it prevents but as per another textbook small gaps allow passage of electron.I have submit assignment that's why Im doing this. Please tell

Comment: No. If it just said "small" it would not make sense. The statement is clear but (according to you) false. The only typing error ("print mistake") is the one I mentioned.

Comment: Can't it be like this
It is so small to prevent electron passage.as a idiomatic sentence

Comment: So sir last what should I write?

Answer (score 1):

From your comments on the other answers, I have noticed the source of your confusion is this part of NCERT's chemistry textbook

> …consider the case of Cr, which has 3d⁵4s¹ configuration instead of 3d⁴4s²; the energy gap between the two sets (3d and 4s) of orbitals is small enough to prevent electron entering the 3d orbitals.

I say your English skills are not the problem. You have understood the statement correctly, for what they have mentioned.

It looks like there actually is a mistake in the book. It should be *permit* instead of *prevent*

Refer to this answer on chemistry stack exchange for more explanation
https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/162657/exceptional-electronic-configuration-of-chromium

It's a good habit to always mention the original question you have, instead of making up a similar question. Because there can always be unexpected answers like this

Answer (score 0):

Big an heavy implies physical properties - such that one would expect physical ability to deal with physical tasks implied by the sentence. Or the counter point where one is not so that they can't do such works.
The latter does not seem like a sentence that would be uttered since it undermines this premise - one does not expect a small person to be able to do heavy work.

Comment: Hi could please see and help
https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/144253/about-d-block-elements

Comment: That question there implies that there are smaller things that would work but from my recollection of chemistry either you are in the right electron orbits or not.  So in this case it's being used as a comparative - "anything else would be too big".