# “He is small enough to walk.” But baby wasn't walking so why didn't they use “small” instead of “small enough”?

Tags: adjectives

I'm confused because in my textbook there's a sentence:

> He is *small enough* to walk.

because baby was so small that he couldn't walk.

Why didn't they just use *small* instead of *small enough*?

Comment: If it were a baby, it would have been referred to as "it". But I must say your textbook gives a rather strange example. Provide more context if you have.

Comment: Your previous question https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/270111/big-enough-to-do-this answered the meaning of "small enough".  What is different about this?  Please add some more context.  Does "He" mean "the baby"?  Did you get the quote correct.  As it stands the the question means "He was sufficiently small to walk"  Which doesn't make much sence (Babies learn to walk as they get bigger)

Comment: Ok it's right one"he is small enough to do such heavy works"it is used for a man who is very skinny, so I'm just asking why they didn't use just small instead of small enough

Comment: Does this mean he is so small that he cannot do such works, if so why use small enough

Comment: "He is small enough to walk" means that big babies can't  walk, but he is small so he can walk.

Comment: Sir please see this and help
https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/144253/about-d-block-elements

Comment: The sentence about the skinny man makes more sense. It is an idiomatic way of saying "He's very small to do such heavy work", meaning that it is a lot to expect of such a small man.

Comment: Kate could you please see and help me here
https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/144253/about-d-block-elements

Comment: And the chemistry reference is about a gap being _small enough_ to prevent electrons from passing through - that is, not big enough for them to pass through.

Comment: Kate but electron is passing because there is a small gap if the gap was big it wouldn't pass. So I guess it could be misprint or idiomatic? Please help

Comment: If you want to ask about the sentence in the chemistry post, you should edit your question to ask about that sentence. If you want to ask about the sentence about the baby, it seems the sentence is just nonsensical (because normally babies start walking when they get bigger, not when they get smaller).

Answer (score 1):

> He is small enough to walk.

This means that if he were bigger, he couldn't walk.

Obviously this doesn't agree with our usual experience with babies, which normally start walking when they get bigger.

Possibly the discussion is about "walking the baby", that is, pushing the baby around in a stroller (aka pram), and the meaning is that if the baby were bigger it would be more difficult to walk the baby.

In comments you also asked about this sentence in a Chemistry Stack Exchange post,

> the energy gap between the two sets (3d and 4s) of orbitals is small enough to prevent electron entering the 3d orbitals.

This means that if the gap were bigger it would not prevent electrons entering the 3d orbital; but since it is small it does prevent electrons entering the 3d orbital.

There is no grammatical or syntactical error here.

As a more concrete example, where I live it's common that to enter a hiking trail there is a gate that is *big enough* for a walker to pass through, but *small enough* to prevent a car from driving through:

[image]

Comment: But it contradicts with electron excitation, because it says if energy gap is small then electron can excite between orbitals.so don't you think they have misprinted it or I didn't get it or it should be small instead of small enough. Help me.

Comment: @Mia203, I don't know enough about the chemistry to say, but there is nothing wrong with the grammar in the sentence you quoted. It means that if it were bigger, electrons could enter the 3d orbital. If you replaced *small enough* with just *small* the meaning would not be clear to me at all.

Comment: @Mia203 - small _enough_. This is what you don't understand - what the word 'enough' is doing.

Comment: @Mia203 - the energy gap between the two sets (3d and 4s) of orbitals is _small enough_ to _prevent_ an electron entering the 3d orbitals. The energy gap is _sufficiently small_ that an electron _cannot_ enter the 3d orbitals. A 1 cm hole is _small enough_ that a dog cannot pass through it.

Comment: Michael can we use not big enough and small enough interchangeably?

Comment: @Mia203, they don't mean the same thing. "Not big enough" means too small to do something. "Small enough" means not too big to do it. (In the first case it can't be done, in the second case it can)